# API Gateway WebSocket handle errors

Tags: websocket, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm setting a websocket app with API Gateway. I configured route responses for my lambda functions, so I'm able to handle these responses in my client side.

In my server, I return my response like this:

```
callback (null, {
  statusCode: 500,
  body: 'Some text.'
})
```

In my Websocket client side, the message event (`onmessage`) is triggered by this response.

The `event.data` contains the response body, due to lambda proxy integration response.

However, I can't find a way to trigger the error event (`onerror`), while my `statusCode` says that an error occured (500).

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Lambda function callbacks have the following structure: `callback(error, result)`.

So for errors you would call it like `callback(error)` and for a successful result `callback(null, result)`.

So what you shall be getting on your app is a success response (status code 200) which contains some data that has a field statusCode with value 500. So, as this is a successful response, it should not trigger `onerror` callback, but rather only `onmessage`.

My suggestion is that you handle status code response's other than 200 also inside your `onmessage` method and the `onerror` handler for errors other than the ones catch and retrieved from your lambda function (for example an AWS Api Gateway issue, a network issue, etc).